# Xpath seems didn't return expected span

Tags: python, xpath

I am trying to use xpath to download all images from a webpage.
Have managed to found the specific element which has several spans, and the full xpath looks as below:

```
/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/main/ul/li[4]/article/div[1]/a/span/span[1]
/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/main/ul/li[4]/article/div[1]/a/span/span[2]
/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/main/ul/li[4]/article/div[1]/a/span/span[3]
```

etc.

Currently I've get the whole element till "li[4]" level and tried to use below code to find all the leaves elements of the tree, but the returned value is empty:

```
->node.xpath('./article/div[@class="flex-box"]/a/span[starts-with(@class,"grid-box")]/span')
->[]
```

And the parent node length is only 1 instead of the number of the leaves which I expected to be at least 4-5 here:

```
->len(node.xpath('./article/div[@class="flex-box"]/a/span[starts-with(@class,"grid-box")]'))
->1
->node.xpath('./article/div[@class="flex-box"]/a/span[starts-with(@class,"grid-box")]')[0]
-><Element span at 0x1ac51134040>
```

Any one could help me figure out what is going on here?

Comment: It seems this part of the whole page is generated from an ajax code called "get-fb-posts-ajax" so basically my way of getting the page source will not see them